# Node.js multiple database server connection on SQL SERVER

Tags: node.js, sql-server, api, express

I need to use three database servers at the same time. Is there a way how to do it?
Here's the process I need to do.

Server1[SELECT] -> Server2[Insert] -> Server1[Update(Received)], Server3[Insert] -> Server2[Update(Received)]

Doing this process multiple times.

I getting an error

> Cannot close a pool while it is connecting

Comment: Could you show the code that throws this error?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to make three separate calls to three separate servers.
If I also understand correctly, what's happening is, you're making a call to the first server using your client, then as you try to talk to another server, your client says that it has closed the connection.
What you will need to do is have three separate clients, each having its own connection to the server, and using those separately.

The community could provide you with much better answers if you follow @KDani-99's suggestion and post a snippet of your code.